# Redirect a WordPress subdomen from WWW to non-WWW

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to redirect www.udemy1.make4u.eu to udemy1.make4u.eu, but it doesn't work. 
I get this error **DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN**. I use Cloudflare for my website. 
In **.htaccess** I have this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.udemy1.make4u.eu [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://udemy1.make4u.eu/$1 [L,R=301]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Can you help me?

***Update***

I have this, but it doens't work

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.udemy1.make4u.eu [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://udemy1.make4u.eu/$1 [L,R=301]


</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

The “L” in the brackets at the end of a line mean to stop processing rewrites after the current one. Thus your custom rewrite should probably go before the WordPress ones.

I also believe you need to escape the periods in the RewriteCond line:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.udemy1\.make4u\.eu [NC]`

Personally I would move it entirely outside of the block created by WordPress itself so that WordPress doesn’t overwrite it.

Comment: Ok, I've just done like you said. It doesn't work. Mayby it is problem with cloudflare?

Comment: It doen't work. I get this massage "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"

Comment: That appears to be a separate issue.  Google the exact error and you'll see a lot of people talking about it.

Answer (score 0):

The error "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN" is the code you get in Google Chrome when you're trying to connect to a domain that doesn't exist.

I just checked in my terminal:

```
$ host www.udemy1.make4u.eu
Host www.udemy1.make4u.eu not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
$ host udemy1.make4u.eu
udemy1.make4u.eu has address 104.27.185.117
udemy1.make4u.eu has address 104.27.184.117
```

You need to update your DNS entries for your domain. It seems that one DOES exist for `udemy1.make4u.eu` but you are MISSING an entry for `www.udemy1.make4u.eu`.

I think this happens a lot. People assume that `www.` "just works" without configuring it, but it's no different than any other subdomain like `ftp.` or `mail.` etc.. (except that `www.` is more popular).

Follow the [CloudFlare Support documentation for creating a CNAME](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168706-How-do-I-do-CNAME-setup-) and create your new `www.udemy1` CNAME record. I met you could set the CNAME value for `www.udemy1` to literally `udemy1.make4u.eu` and it would resolve just fine.

Comment: Ok, I did it, but now I have problem with **ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH**, what now?